# Как упростить решение этой задачи

Tags: python

2^15 = 32768, сумма цифр этого числа равна 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.

Какова сумма цифр числа 2^1000?

```
n = 2
s = 0
st = 1000
for i in range (st):
    n *= 2

n = str(n)
for i in range (len(n)):
    n = int(n)
    s = s + n%10
    n //= 10

print (s)
```

Comment: `sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))`.

Comment: Ваша задача, скорее всего, является математической проблемой, а не программаторской.

Answer (score 3):

например:

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in str(2**1000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает обработки ошибки при переполнении.

```
def power(base, exponent):
    MAX_SIZE = 1000
    result = [0] * MAX_SIZE

    result[-1] = base
    current_size = 1

    for _ in range(1, exponent):
        carry = 0
        for position in range(MAX_SIZE - 1, MAX_SIZE - current_size - 1, -1):
            product = result[position] * base + carry
            result[position] = product % 10
            carry = product // 10
        if carry > 0:
            current_size += 1
            result[MAX_SIZE - current_size] = carry

    return result[MAX_SIZE - current_size:]


print(power(2, 15))
print(''.join(map(str, power(2, 15))))
print(sum(power(2, 15)))

print(power(2, 1000))
print(''.join(map(str, power(2, 1000))))
print(sum(power(2, 1000)))
```

**Результат**:

```
# [3, 2, 7, 6, 8]
# '32768'
# 26

# [1, 0, 7, 1, 5, 0, 8, 6, 0, 7, 1, 8, 6, 2, 6, 7, 3, 2, 0, 9, 4, 8, 4, 2, 5, 0, 4, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 5, 6, 1, 4, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 0, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 0, 7, 4, 4, 3, 7, 5, 0, 3, 8, 8, 3, 7, 0, 3, 5, 1, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 9, 3, 1, 9, 8, 3, 7, 8, 8, 1, 5, 6, 9, 5, 8, 5, 8, 1, 2, 7, 5, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2, 9, 1, 7, 5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5, 1, 8, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 6, 9, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 4, 3, 5, 9, 8, 4, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 8, 5, 7, 4, 8, 0, 3, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 4, 8, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, 7, 4, 6, 0, 5, 0, 6, 2, 3, 7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 8, 7, 7, 9, 5, 4, 1, 8, 2, 1, 5, 3, 0, 4, 6, 4, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 5, 8, 1, 9, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 5, 5, 9, 1, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 9, 4, 6, 0, 7, 7, 0, 6, 2, 9, 1, 4, 5, 7, 1, 1, 9, 6, 4, 7, 7, 6, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 6, 6, 0, 4, 2, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 6, 8, 3, 7, 2, 0, 5, 6, 6, 8, 0, 6, 9, 3, 7, 6]
# '10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376'
# 1366
```

Comment: А проверки на переполнение чего? :)

Comment: @gil9red если попробовать посчитать 1000^1000, то в массив из 1000 элементов не влезет

Comment: Было же про `2 ^ 100` а это число с 302 цифрами, да и так ли нужен тут массив?

Answer (score 0):

```
c = 2
s = 0
b = ''
for i in range(999):
    c = c*2
c = str(c)
for i in range(len(c)):
    b = c[i]
    s += int(b) 
print(s)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]